# Web scraper using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am new to C# so this might be very obvious how to get this to work or way too complex for me but I am trying to setup and scrape a web page using the HtmlAgilityPack. Currently my code compiles but when I write the string I only get 1 result and it happens to be the last result from the li in the ul. The reason for the string split is so I can eventually output the title and description strings into a .csv for further use. I am just unsure what to do next thus, why I am asking for any help/understanding/ideas/thoughts/suggestions that can be offered. Thank you!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> cities = new List<string>();
        //var xpath = "//h2[span/@id='Cities']";
        var xpath = "//h2[span/@id='Cities']" + "/following-sibling::ul[1]" + "/li";

        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        String html = web.DownloadString("http://wikitravel.org/en/Vietnam");

        hap.HtmlDocument doc = new hap.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);


        foreach (hap.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)) 
        {
            string all = node.InnerText;

            //splits text between '—', '-' or ' ' into 2 parts
            string[] split = all.Split(new char[] { '—', ' ', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            string title;
            string description;

            int nodeCount;
            nodeCount = node.ChildNodes.Count;

            if (nodeCount == 2)
            {
                title = node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                description = node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
            }
            else if (nodeCount == 4)
            {
                title = node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                description = node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText + node.ChildNodes[2].InnerText;
            }
            else
            {
                title = "Error";
                description = "The node cound was not 2 or 3.  Check the div section.";
            }

            System.IO.StreamWriter write = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\cbrannin\Desktop\textTest\testText.txt");
            write.WriteLine(all);

            write.Close();


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you're overwriting the output file each time through the loop. You probably want to do this:

```
using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"filename"))
{
    foreach (hap.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath))
    {
        // do your thing
        write.WriteLine(all);
    }
}
```

Also, have you single-stepped this to see if you're getting more than one `HtmlNode` from your `SelectNode` call?

Finally, I don't see where you're doing anything with the `title` or `description`. Were you planning to use those for something else?

Comment: That print worked perfectly and I am a fool for placing the using in the wrong spot to begin with. All cities are now printing to the text file. The reason for the title and description are to have the name of the city fill that string then have the city description fill the description string, so I can setup a .csv file to use this data later on. That was the reason for split on these characters '—', ' ', '-'. The idea is to setup this data into .csv format, key word is idea... Thank you for the response!